# Find all non trivial homorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Find all non trivial homorphisms from group $D_5 \to \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

I have problem here since $\mathbb D_5$ is no cyclic group. I know that $o(f(a)) | o(a)$ where $f$ is homomorphism

Comment: $D_5$ is the dihedral group of order $10$?

Comment: @Ihf yes $D_5 $ is dihedral of order 10

Comment: The dihedral group has $5$ elements of order $2$, $4$ elements of order $5$ and one identity element. $5$ of those elements you can place rather easily, the other $5$ might need a bit of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $D_5$ is the dihedral group of order $10$, then it is generated by two elements $r$ of order $2$ and $s$ of order $5$ satisfying $sr=rs^4$. So, every element of $D_5$ is of the form $r^i s^j$, with $i=0,1$ and $j=0,\dots,4$.

Every homomorphism $D_5 \to Z_2 \times Z_2$ must send $s$ to $e$ and so is determined by where it sends $r$.

The problem is thus reduced to finding all elements of order $2$ in $Z_2 \times Z_2$.

Comment: why $sr=rs^4$ and where we are using it since if $<r,s>=D_5$ then we have every element is of the form $r^i  s^j$ or not ?

Comment: @Mat, if your definition of $D_5$ is geometric, just check that $sr=rs^4$. Since every element in $D_5$ is a word in $r,s,r^{-1}=r,s^{-1}=4$, every element can be reduced to $r^is^j$.

Comment: @Ihf but can I say that since $<r,s>$ generates $D_5$ and we know that $D_5=\{e, s ,s^2, .. , s^4, r, sr, …, s^4r  \}$ then every element of $D_5$ is of form $s^jr^i$ where $j=0,..,4$, $r=0,1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the element of order $5$. Then $f(x)=e$, since $o(f(x))$ divides $4$ by Cauchy, and $5$ is prime, so $o(a)$ cannot be divided by any divisor of $4$ except $1$. Thus we have that any homomorphism sends $x$ to $e$. Thus all homomorphisms factor as $D_5\to D_5/(x)=\mathbb{Z}/(2)\to \mathbb{Z}/(2)\oplus \mathbb{Z}/(2)$. But these can be seen to consist of sending $y$, the order $2$ element, to $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ or $(1, 1)$!